# Python Selenium "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a small Python app that simply records a webpage / web animation with Selenium and FFmpeg. Worked like a charm until yesterday.

It seems that Google has removed the "--disable-infobars" feature. Can this be disabled from another flag or function?

Or am I forced to add padding to the top and record from the padding?

**Here's an example code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "http://foo.bar"

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':99'
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()
display_port = os.environ['DISPLAY']

chrome_driver_path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--kiosk')
options.add_argument('--window-position=0,0')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars');
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=options)
browser.get(url)

command = "/home/fidox/bin/ffmpeg -r 60 -t {} -video_size {}x{} -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i foo.mp4 f-an {}".format(10,1920,1080,display_port)
os.system(command) 

self.browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

Comment: Post chrome browser version, and chrome driver version...as `--disable-infobars` working for me

Answer (score 7):

For Python3.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update to Chrome 65? If you go to view about Chrome it'll auto update. Chromedriver appears broken in Chrome 65. You can uninstall and reinstall Chrome 64.

Comment: Chrome seems to have auto updated. Can I turn off auto update function? Feels sad to stay on 64, but if thats the only solution then I’ll have to face that

Comment: You can try updating your chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads also Giving that a go myself right now.

Comment: The flag is removed since 65 https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869ab3350d8ebd95222b4a47adf87ce3d3214b1

Answer (score 0):

`disable-infobars` flag has been removed but you can get rid of the message by adding the following:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This work for me and I hope works for you too.

Don't know how to do this in python.
kindly convert above code accordingly.